# Java. word positioning in a string

Tags: java, string

I am currently programming java and have been asked to develop a program that analyses a sentence that contains several words without punctuation. when a word in that sentence is input, the program identifies all of the positions where that word occurs in that string..

String example:

> ASK NOT WHAT YOUR COUNTRY CAN DO FOR YOU, ASK WHAT YOU CAN DO FOR YOUR COUNTRY.

Code:

```
String Scan_word;
Scan_word = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Word to be scanned for");

String Full_Scan;
Full_Scan = "You have entered " + Scan_word + " "; // the input dialog box will display this when a word is inputted
String sentence = "Ask not what your country should do for you but what you should do for you country"; //The sentence 

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, Full_Scan);
if (sentence.contains(Scan_word)); {
    String[] sentenceWords = sentence.split(" ");

    for (int i = 0; i < sentenceWords.length; i++) {
        if (sentenceWords[i].equals(Scan_word)); {
    }     System.out.println(Scan_word + " is located in the: " + i + "th position");
}
```

ALL code is in Static void section as should be.

SORRY IT HAS CODING COMMENTS.
PLS ignore the CAQ1STOPBLOCKINGTHEM title as my netbeans projects were being locked for no reason or another.

Comment: You interrupt the if with a `;`: `if (sentence.contains(Scan_word)); {`

Comment: an offtopic comment, I suggest you review your naming system and follow standard ones: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

Comment: Cheers for your comment :) I will check the website out and it should help me :)

Answer (score 2):

Your bug seems to be related to your `if` that is not properly written, indeed you put a semicolon just after it meaning that there no instruction to launch, moreover you print your message outside the curly brackets and finally you should print the value of `i + 1` not `i` since it starts from `0`, so your code should rather be:

```
if (sentenceWords[i].equals(Scan_word)) {
    System.out.println(Scan_word + " is located in the: " + (i + 1) + "th position");
}
```

Consider reading some articles about the naming conventions in java like [this one](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) for example. In a nutshell, a varaiable name should start with a lower case.

Comment: some recommendation for refactoring variable names wont hurt any puppet `:P`

Comment: Cheers for your reply. this should hopefully fix the problem :)